# When we create SSL enabled Service, do we have to hand out certificates to each client?

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

One of my teammate just enabled SSL on one of the service that we are using and I had to install a **Certificate** that he gave me to each of the client machines who intend to consume that service. Now, I am not very well-versed when it comes to SSL security and that raised a question in my mind that

1. WHENEVER we create a SSl enabled service, do we have to hand out certificate to all the clients
2. Is there any kind of configuration using which we create an SSL enabled service without having to hand out certificate to all the clients?

   3. IF it is possible then how secured that service be than the service which requires each client to install certificate on the machine?

Also, is there any easy to understand article on WCF SSL security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Que : WHENEVER we create a SSl enabled service, do we have to hand out certificate to all the clients

Ans : No. For SSL enabled service one do not need to handout certificates to clients.
SSL certificate on server (in this case service) side gives confidence to clients that they are talking to legitimate server.
Clients needs certificates only in case of when service needs its clients to prove their identity using client certificate. With client certificate server (service) gets confidence that its sending data to legitimate clients.

2. Que : Is there any kind of configuration using which we create an SSL enabled service without having to hand out certificate to all the clients?

Ans : Certainly there is way with which you can make service enabled without requiring client certificate. Check SSL Settings option for website where service is hosted.

3. Que: IF it is possible then how secured that service be than the service which requires each client to install certificate on the machine?

Ans : Obliviously using SSL certificate doesn't stop any clients from consuming it. Any client who knows service endpoint can consume it. Client certificate is one way to authenticate clients. Only those clients who has valid client certificate will be able to consume service.

4. Que: Also, is there any easy to understand article on WCF SSL security?

Ans : Check out this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx Its WCF regarding security as whole and not just SSL security.